# Creating a vector with specific values out of a colSums(DF)

Tags: r, vector

I have the following DF:

```
> str(fngr_rain)
'data.frame':   80 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ CRP: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CRO: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ EPR: int  1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ EPO: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ARB: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ OPP: int  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 ...
 $ AAT: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ LCA: int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ATN: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I want to create a function which makes a vector of the colSums of this DF. The catch is: I need the vector to have only the values of colSums which are greater than 4. So, instead of this:

```
> colSums(fngr_rain)
CRP CRO EPR EPO ARB OPP AAT LCA ATN 
  3   0  48  80   3  51   1  25   0
```

I want the following vector:

```
> vector1 <- c("EPR" = 48, "EPO" = 80, "OPP" = 51, "LCA" = 25)
> vector1
EPR EPO OPP LCA 
 48  80  51  25
```

I was trying something like this:

```
> my_fun = function(x) {
+     sapply(as.vector(colSums(x)), function(x){
+         if(x >= 4) assign("my_vec", x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
+         }
+     )
+ }
> my_fun(fngr_rain)
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
[1] 3

[[6]]
NULL

[[7]]
[1] 1

[[8]]
NULL

[[9]]
[1] 0
```

EDIT:
It returns me a list with the vector. I can then get the vector using unlist() (as shown in the comments)

```
unlist(my_fun(fngr_rain))
[1] 3 0 3 1 0
```

However, I still wanted the vector to be stored in an object. I tried to do that in my function, but the "my_vec" object I created does not return me the vector:

```
> my_vec
[1] 0
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: why didn't it work looks like it just gave you a list of your answers? Try `unlist(my_fun(fngr_rain)`

Comment: I did want a function to store the vector in an object...but I guess I can do with this, thanks.

Comment: to store the vector as object; `Results <- unlist(my_fun(fngr_rain)`

Comment: `Results` will now be your object containing colsums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
colSums(fngr_rain)[colSums(fngr_rain)>4]
```